# Enum : get the keys list

Tags: java, enums

I'm looking forward to using the "google-api-translate-java" library.
In which there is a [Language](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/api/translate/Language.java) class. It's an enum allowing to provide the language name and to get it's value for Google Translate.

I can easily get all the values with :

```
for (Language l : values()) {
    // Here I loop on one value
}
```

But what I'd want to get is a list of all the keys names (FRENCH, ENGLISH, ...).
Is there something like a "keys()" method that'd allow me to loop through all the enum's keys ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative to `Language.values()` is to use [`EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```
for (Language l : EnumSet.allOf(Language.class))
{
}
```

This is useful if you want to use it in an API which uses the collections interfaces instead of an array. (It also avoids creating the array to start with... but needs to perform other work instead, of course. It's all about trade-offs.)

In this particular case, `values()` is probably more appropriate - but it's worth at least knowing about `EnumSet`.

EDIT: Judging by another comment, you have a concern about `toString()` being overridden - call `name()` instead:

```
for (Language l : Language.values())
{
    String name = l.name();
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for (Language l : Language.values()) {
    l.name();
}
```

See also:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/Enumvalues.htm
- http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html
- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes - If the enum is X, use X.values(). See in [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: I tried that. But the library redefines the toString() method. So what I get is still the value and not the key.

Comment: @Damien: See the edit to my answer. Basically you're after name()